# Script to identify if a folder exists and if it does not create it in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have the following script:

```
function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
  try {
    var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents();
    pastavideo = folders.next().getParents().next();
    var foldersIter = pastavideo.getFoldersByName("01-01"),
      parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId),
      folder;

    if (parentFolder) {
      if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
        folder = foldersIter.next();
      } else {
        folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video").createFolder("01-01");
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
    }

    return folder.getId();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

My folder structure is as follows

```
parentFolder > Video > 01-01
```

The idea is that this script checks if the `Video` folder and the `01-01` folder exist, if they don't exist I want it to create them.

The problem is that the way the script is written it is not doing the verification, just creating several folders `Video` and `01-01` inside the parent folder.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what does the line pastavideo = `folders.next().getParents().next();` do in your code please ?

Comment: At first, nothing, I posted exactly where I left off in my attempts, I created it trying to use it in the variable `var foldersIter`

Comment: I think you are doing it right, except that you need to reorder a few lines, and maybe  some block of `if` to be changed also... 
well I tried to do some updated on you code, try it and tell me what did you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentionned in the comment, I think the code provided is on the right way, it still lacks a few lines to be ordered, try this:

`var foldersIter = pastavideo.getFoldersByName("01-01")` is changed to var `foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video")`

Then, inside the if (parentFolder) block, make sure that the foldersIter object has a next element. If it does, assign it to the folder variable. If not, create a new folder "Video" in the parentFolder, then create a new folder "01-01" in the folder "Video".

```
function createOrGetFolder(folderName, parentFolderId) {
  try {
    var ssid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents();
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId),
      folder;

    if (parentFolder) {
  var foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("Video");
  if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
    video_folder = foldersIter.next().getFoldersByName("01-01");
    if (video_folder.hasNext()) {
    folder = video_folder.next();
    }
  } else {
    folder = parentFolder.createFolder("Video");
    folder = folder.createFolder("01-01");
  }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Parent Folder with id: " + parentFolderId + " not found");
    }

    return folder.getId();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience for the explanation, from your explanation I am able to understand a little better the operation of the `next()` and `hasNext()` parameters. The code is doing almost what I need, I'm using this function to upload a file in folder `01-01`. In the way you formulated it, when the folders `Video > 01-01` exist, the video is being uploaded to the `Video` folder, if they don't exist, it is going to the folder `01-01`, which is the objective.

Comment: I tried to add this: `if (foldersIter.hasNext()) { video_folder = foldersIter.next() if (video_folder.hasNext()) { folder = video_folder.next().getFoldersByName("01-01"); }` but the file still went to the `Video` folder

Comment: Hey, I managed to solve the issue of uploading inside folder `01-01`, based on your answer I deduced that I needed to add an `If` section, and it really worked!

I didn't know what was the best way to post this, I tried to post it here in the comment but it was a mess so I edited your answer, sorry if it's not the best way.

Again, thank you very much for your help and detailed explanation!

Comment: Happy to hear that, I just approved your update. 
Happy coding :)